# Close an instance of excel from within a .net visual basic application Excel asks to save file

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have a .net visual basic application which opens a .xls file by starting up an instance of excel.  I process the data in the file and then close the worksheet prior to exiting my application.  All code in the application works fine, the application does what it is supposed to do.  The only issue is that when I close the instance of the worksheet, Excel asks if I want to save the file by displaying the Save File dialog box.  This is the code that I am executing:

```
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim xlsFileName as string = "path to my .xls file"

        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlsFileName)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet

        Dim range As Excel.Range
        range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange
        numberOfDataRecords = range.Rows.Count
        numberOfColumns = range.Columns.Count


        this is where I process the worksheet data


        xlWorkBook.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
        xlApp.Quit()
```

Am I not closing the workbook correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: You may try `xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False` before closing.

Answer (score 1):

Put this before the close:

```
xlWorkBook.saved = true
```

It makes Excel think you have already saved the workbook. I don't know why but I have had to do this even though you are specifically saying not to save changed.

Comment: I just tried this but it still displays the save as dialog box.  @RobertBaron said to try xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False before the close and that seems to have done the trick.  Thanks

Comment: In this case I would imagine there is another workbook open that is what Excel is prompting to save. You can poll through and close 1 after the other if you like but if the blanket suppression of dialog boxes works for you then there is little benefit to this other than education or curiosity satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False` before closing.

Comment: @Jonathan Small - If this answers your question, then please accept it :-)